# use data outside of .subscribe in typescript file

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic4, angular8

I am very new to typescript/ionic 4. I am trying to access data stored in firebase and use it in my typescript file. when in .subscribe I can display the data as requested. but this is not what I am looking for. I need to perform the calculation outside of .subscribe on my page.ts .

I have seen many similar issues, but I cannot seem to get a solution.

Here is my **Typescript** services file

```
  export interface Place{
    title: string;
    type: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
 }
 export class PlaceService {
 placess: Place[];
 place: Place;
 private placesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Place>;
 private places: Observable<Place[]>;

 constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.placesCollection = db.collection<Place>('places');

    this.places = this.placesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions =>{
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return{ id, ...data};
      });
    })
  );
 }
 getPlaces() {
    return this.places;
 }
 }
```

and the relevant part in my page **typescript**

```
import { PlaceService, Place } from '../services/place.service';

places: Place[];
ngOnInit() {
this.placeService.getPlaces()
  .subscribe(res =>{
  this.places = res;
  console.log(this.places[0].title);//WORKS
});

console.log(this.places[0].title);//FAILED
 }
```

I get the following error message:

```
 MapPage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Where do you need the `this.places`? On .html page or on the .ts page?

Comment: on the ts page, sorry thought I included that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your code works as you wrote it. When the page initializes the `ngOnInit` is called. Inside the code goes to the first element (this.placeService.getPlaces() ... ) and immediately goes to the seconde element (console.log(this.places[0]). This throws the error, because the `places` variable is not yet set from your call to the placeService and is currently `undefined`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.placeService.getPlaces() // called first
    .subscribe(res =>{
    this.places = res;
    console.log(this.places[0].title);
});

console.log(this.places[0].title); // called second (undefined error)
}
```

If you call a function after you set the `places` variable, the second console.log() will work.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.placeService.getPlaces()
    .subscribe(res =>{
    this.places = res;
    console.log(this.places[0].title);
    this.showFirstTitle(); // this.places is set
  });
}

showFirstTitle() {
  console.log(this.places[0].title); // will work
}
```

Comment: this.places is an interface defined in the place.service.ts, but I have got around that problem, how can I get it to wait for this.placeService to complete??

Comment: @SteveQsack no that can't be, `this.places` on your page has to be a variable declared under your Ionic4 page. `export class YourPage implements OnInit {   places: any = []; ... `

Comment: I have updated my code to show what I did, I exported the interface created in place.service.ts and declared it in map.page.ts. I am not sure why it insists on me using .this. but I declared a new object array and copied the contents of this.places into it (if I use setTimeout() it works). do you know how can I get my code to wait for the .subscribe to collect all the data, so I do not need to use setTimeout??

Comment: @SteveQsack i'm not a fan of setTimeout as they tend to miss some core concepts of observables and promises. Check my update, if you call a function after you subscribed on the data, that data will pass and show in console.log

Answer (score 0):

.subscribe method has to complete( ajax request has to be 200-OK), inside subscribe method you can store into your local variables, Then further modifications are possible.

you can not use a variable which has no data.

```
this.placeService.getPlaces()
  .subscribe(res =>{
  this.places = res;  
});
```

will take some seconds to complete the ajax call and fetch the response and storing in "Places".

workaround(not recommended) use `set timeout function`  wait for at least 2 sec. increment seconds until you find a minimal seconds that request and response completed.

then you can do some calculations on `this.places`.

Comment: Hi, I dont think this is the issue. gave it a shot but no luck.

Comment: @SteveQsack When you try to access **this.places[0].title** this is what you get right?
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined**

Comment: error message added, error is unchanged with adding setTimeout

Comment: @SteveQsack **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**, this.places is not an array and have no data init, You have to wait for **subscribe()**  to load data.

Comment: @SteveQsack did you Tried
`setTimeout(function(){ 
this.placeService.getPlaces()
  .subscribe(res =>{
  this.places = res;
});

 }, 3000); 
console.log(this.places[0].title);
`

Comment: @SteveQsack can you console log **res** , make sure you are not sending any nested data, if so do this `this.places = res.data`.